# Criando e consumindo webService PHP+JSON - Não consigo fazer a configuração

Tags: php, web-service

Estou fazendo um webservice, sem nenhum framework, usando PHP+JSON, com localhost xampp inicialmente, assim que pronto colocarei em algum servidor cloud.

Criei no xampp/htdocs duas pastas, "cliente" e "fornecedor", futuramente 'cliente' estará em um servidor e 'fornecedor' em outro, onde em cliente será o acesso do usuário enviando dados através de um formulário via cURL, e no fornecedor haverá o recebimento desses dados e disponibilizará informações para retorno na interface do cliente. Por enquanto não estou usando banco de dados, mas logo implementarei, acredito que para esse mecanismo inicial não seja necessário bd.

Para processar os dados do formulário enviados pelo cliente, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
$url = "http://127.0.0.1/ws/fornecedor/wsClientRequire.php";    

  $cURL = curl_init($url);

  curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  // Definimos um array seguindo o padrão:
  //  '<name do input>' => '<valor inserido>'
  $dados = array(
    'nome' => 'John da silva',
    'email' => 'contato@johnDaSilva.net',
    'mensagem' => 'Testando o cURL!'
  );

  // Iremos usar o método POST
  curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);

  // Definimos quais informações serão enviadas pelo POST (array)
  curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dados);

  $resultado = curl_exec($cURL);

  $resposta = curl_getinfo($cURL, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  curl_close($cURL);

  if ($resposta == '404') {
        echo 'O site está fora do ar (ERRO 404)!';
  } else {
        echo 'Parece que está tudo bem...';
  }

    //var_dump(json_decode($jsonRet, true)); //com var_dump aparece NULL

    $retorno = json_decode($jsonRet);
    $success = $retorno->data->success;                                                                             
    echo " \n success: ".$success;
```

---

Nesse trecho:

```
$retorno = json_decode($jsonRet);
    $success = $retorno->data->success;                                                                               
    echo " \n success: ".$success;
```

Esperava receber a informação contida no arquivo do fornecedor... mas isso não aconteceu... Então gostaria de saber como fazer essa parte de configuração do web service. Fiz assim no fornecedor:

```
$success = "Recebido com sucesso.";
 $message = null;
 $dados = array();

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'success' => $success,
            'message' => $message,
            'dados'   => $dados
        )
    );

    exit;
```

---

A comunicação entre cliente e fornecedor não ocorreu como desejado... alguém sabe como resolver???

Para deixar mais claro minha pergunta... no "fornecedor" que é o ultimo código que postei, como faço para ler os dados que o cliente enviou via cURL? e como faço para disponibilizar um retorno, que será apresentado na interface do cliente? Como faço para enviar os headers via cURL no arquivo do "cliente", nesse headers no cUrl setopt seria necessario enviar uma espécie de token para autorização de acesso, e como faço para ler esse header token no arquivo do fornecedor?

Comment: você já testou o fornecedor e ele está acessível? Ou realmente sua dúvida é como pegar os dados enviados do cliente?

Comment: Oi @TurqSpl consegui fazer a comunicação. Precisava colocar um $_POST['nome'] no fornecedor para poder receber os dados do cliente. Agora minha duvida ainda pendente, é como enviar os headers via cURL do cliente para o fornecedor, nos headers precisaria ser enviado uma especie de token para autorização de uso.

Comment: Quando coloco header, dessa forma: 
   curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          'APIKEY: 111111111111111111111',
          'Content-Type: application/json',
          //$headers
       ));   * Dessa forma o $_POST não funciona...

Comment: Já tentou utilizar `file_get_contents('php://input')`?

Comment: Oi @GabrielHeming consegui capturar os dados.. agora preciso saber como fazer o header autorization

Comment: ...cmo ler o header authorization na parte do fornecedor

Comment: Existem algumas formas de pegar os cabeçalhos, a mais comum é usando [apache_request_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php). Valide também se na variável $_SERVER não está vindo o cabeçalho. É possivel, também, adicionar via HTACCESS.

Comment: Vou testar o apache_request_headers... quando coloco o CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER no cliente, o fornecedor não recebe mais os dados.. preciso saber como usar o authorization e o fornecedor conseguir receber os dados via $_POST

Comment: no cliente coloquei assim; curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                 
  "Content-Type: application/json",                
 ));   ...e no fornecedor assim: $headers = apache_request_headers();   ...mas nenhum dado nem de post de headers está voltando nem inserindo no BD... alguma authorização deve estar faltando nessa implementação

Comment: e vc sabe como pego um dado especifico com o $headers = apache_request_headers() ?